# [Python]: When would you use the `any(x)` function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, any

I was going through the Python Manual for 3.4 when I came across a built in function that I didn't know about. The function was `any(x)`.

The Python Manual said that this function "Return `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False."

They also wrote code that would be equivalent to this function.

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

What are the uses of this function?

Comment: Normally you'd use it with some sort of condition eg: `if any(i % 2 == 0 for i in some_list_of_numbers)` - to see if there's any even numbers...

Comment: It would also be useful if you understand [what is true and false](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it to avoid multiple similar conditions, for example.

To check if a string contains a list of substrings, you can do:

```
str = 'Your cat is hungry.'

if 'cat' in str:
    print 'Feed it!'
elif 'dog' in str:
    print 'Feed it!'
elif 'hamster' in str:
    print 'Feed it!'
```

...or you can do:

```
str = 'Your cat is hungry.'
pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'hamster']

if any(animal in str for animal in pets):
    print 'Feed it!'
```

#### Update: `if element: return True`.

You are correct - if an element in the iterable has a value, it's `True`. In Python, basically if variable has a value, it's `True` - obviously, as long as the value isn't `False`. Run that example and look at the values and the conditions, maybe it helps more than explanations:

```
x = ' '
y = ''
z = False

if x:
    print 'x is True!'
else:
    print 'x is False!'

if x == True:
    print 'x is True!'
else:
    print 'x is False!'

if y:
    print 'y is True!'
else:
    print 'y is False!'    

if z:
    print 'z is True!'
else:
    print 'z is False!'
```

Now back to `any()`: It takes any iterable, like a list, as an argument - and if *any* value of that iterable is `True` *(hence the name)*, `any()` returns `True`.

There is also a function called `all()` - it's similar to `any()`, but only returns True if *all* values of the iterable are true:

```
print any([1, 2, False])

print all([1, 2, False])
```

#### True and False

It's been mentioned in a comment by  @Burhan Khalid before, but the official docs about what's considered to be `False` should be mentioned here, too:

[Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still confused about the second part of my question `if element: return True`. The question was what does this particular piece of code mean. The way it is stated it seems like if element has a value, then return True.

Answer (score 1):

the any function in python is just like a parallel  connection of switches in a circuit if you like physics.
If any one of the switch is on ,(`if element`) the circuit will be completed and it will glow a bulb connected to it in a series connection.
[image: Indicator bulb will glow if any of the circuit is on]

lets take bulb in the parallel connection as shown in figure as circuits and 
the bulb as the indicator bulb(the result of any)

for an instance , if you have a logical list of True and False,

```
logical_list = [False, False, False, False]
logical_list_1 = [True, False, False, False]

any(logical_list)
False  ## because no circuit is on(True) all are off(False)

any(logical_list_1)
True  ## because one circuit is on(True) remaining three are off(False)
```

or you can think of it as a connection of AND, so if any one of the value of the iterator is False, the Result will be False.

For the case of Strings, scenario is same, just the meaning has been changed

```
'' empty string            -> False
'python' non empty string  -> True
```

try this :

```
trial_list = ['','','','']
trial_list_1 = ['python','','','']

any(trial_list)
False ## logically trial_list is equivalent to [False(''), False(''), False(''), False('')]

any(trial_list_1)
True ## logically trial_list_1 is equivalent to [True('python'), False(''), False('') , False('')]
```

for the case of single non empty string any(non empty string) is always True
for the case of single empty string any(empty string is always False

```
any('')
False

any('python')
True
```

I hope this helps ,,

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I started thinking when you wrote "if any one of the value of the iterator is False, the Result will be False". What does this mean for strings. I know that the any(x) function can be used on strings so what are the criteria for achieving True when dealing with a string.